# How can i access an html variable using PHP

Tags: php, html

```
 $name= $row['name'];
      $price = $row['price'];
      $img = $row['image'];
      $id = $row['order_no'];
      
       echo "<div class='col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center'>
       <div class='card cust-card-bg' style='width: 18rem'>
         <img
           src='foodGallery/$img'
           class='card-img-top cust-card-img'
           
         />
         <div class='card-body d-flex flex-column'>
           <h5 class='card-title primary-text'>$name</h5>
           <p class='card-text'>
             Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
             the bulk of the cards content.
           </p>
           <div
             class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mt-auto'
           >
             <h4 class='primary-text m-0'>$price tk</h4>
             <a href='order.php?' order_id = $id class='btn btn-danger' >Order Item</a>
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>";
```

Here I am trying to to get the value of order_id. I tried using $_GET['order_id] but it says undefined array key

Answer (score -2):

Have you saved order_id from your database (i'm assuming your using a database) into your php code? Note: $_GET is used to get values from the parameter of the URL into your php. If you don't have order_id as a parameter in your url, you are doing it wrong

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer. Also keep in mind that phrases like "you are doing it wrong" do not help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).